# Generic class as parameter with inner type

Tags: json, generics, typescript

I am using [Cerialize](https://github.com/weichx/cerialize) as Json serializer/deserializer.

My Api connector works this way:

```
ApiService.get<T>(endpoint:string):Promise<T>
```

calls

```
ApiConnectorService.get<ApiResponse<T>>(tClazz:{new():T;}, endpoint:string);
```

to deserialize, Cerialize uses class parameter:

```
function Deserialize(json: any, type?: Function | ISerializable): any;
```

So, when I call `ApiService.get<T>(endpoint)`, I call `ApiConnectorService.get<ApiResponse<T>>(ApiResponse, endpoint)` in it.

#### Problem

I can't provide `ApiResponse<T>` as tClazz parameter, compiler says

> TS1109: Expression expected

Is there a way to provide Generic class with its Generic type as parameter? This way, when I call `get<User>()` I get a User in an `ApiResponse<User>` type, at the moment I only get an Object in ApiResponse, which is not whet we need.

Here is the ApiResponse class:

```
export class ApiResponse<T>{

    @deserialize
    data:T;

    @deserializeAs(ErrorData)
    error:ErrorData;

    @deserialize
    meta:Object;
}
```

EDIT: Same error if I want to give an array as class parameter:

```
ApiService.get<Foo[]>(Foo[], '/bar');
```

> TS1109: Expression expected

Comment: @EricMartinez why did you remove Typescript tag? it's a typescript problem since I don't find how to filter parameter with a generic class.

Comment: sorry about that. But I guess I got right with the ng2 tag @Supamiu

Comment: I think yes, it's not really an angular2 related issue indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot, if you look at the transpiled generic class here: [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%3CT%3E%7B%0D%0A%09private%20a%3AT%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(a%3A%20T)%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.a%20%3D%20a%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20a%20%3D%20new%20A%3Cnumber%3E(2)%3B) it looses the generics, so in runtime you have no types so you can't get the type of the generic, meaning, in runtime you cannot know what type is your T. You have to pass the class itself as a parameter. You can use the generics for compilation help, but thats the best you can do.

Comment: Ok but what about arrays? I can't pass array class as parameter, that's a huge problem for api calls and genericity (see my EDIT)

Comment: You should pass the `Array` class because again, no types in runtime. `Foo[]` is same as `Foo2[]` in runtime which is actually just a `[]`

Comment: But problem is that if I pass `Array` as parameter, I get an `Object[]` as result, not a `Foo[]`

Comment: You need to specify the type: [example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%7B%0D%0A%09public%20static%20foo%3CT%3E(tClass%3A%20%7Bnew()%3AT%7D)%3A%20T%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20new%20tClass()%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20a%20%3D%20A.foo%3CA%5B%5D%3E(Array)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(a)%3B)

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that nested generics are not supported, and generics are just compile time construct, I have made a small sample that I hope might be helpful to you:

```
export class User
{
    private name: string;

    constructor(serializedValue: string)
    {
        this.name = serializedValue;
    }
}

export class ApiResponse<T>
{
    constructor(val: T)
    {
        this.data = val;    
    }

    data:T;

    error:string;

    meta:Object;
}

class ApiConnectorService<T>
{
    public get<U extends ApiResponse<T>>(tClazz: {new(s: string):T;}, uClazz: {new(t: T):U;}, endpoint:string): U
    {
        let val = 'user';//get serializedvalue from endpoint
        return new uClazz(new tClazz(val));
    }
}   

class ApiService
{
    public get<T>(tClazz: {new(s: string):T;}, endpoint:string): T
    {
        let s = new ApiConnectorService<T>();
        return s.get(tClazz, ApiResponse, '123').data;
    }
}

let a = new ApiService();
console.log(a.get<User>(User, '12'));
```